# How to construct overlaps DbExpression in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to create a `DbExpression` which will be used in custom `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor` to filter users(user's clients collection must contains at least on item from other list).

Basically I need to convert this Linq statement:

```
  List<int> clientIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
  IQueryable<User> users = _context.Users
        .Include(x => x.Clients)
        .Where(x => x.Clients.Select(cl => cl.Id).Intersect(clientIds).Any());
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `Where(x => x.Clients.Any(client => clientIds.Contains(client.Id))`?

Comment: @Evk Thanks, but you just rewrote my linq statement. But I need a `DbExpression`. See this https://book2s.com/csharp/api/system/system.data.common.commandtrees.expressionbuilder/dbexpressionbuilder/equal-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build such interceptor like this:

```
public class Interceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor {
    private readonly int[] _clientIds;
    public Interceptor(int[] clientIds) {
        _clientIds = clientIds;
    }
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext) {            
        if (interceptionContext.Result.CommandTreeKind == DbCommandTreeKind.Query)
            InterceptQuery(interceptionContext);
    }

    private void InterceptQuery(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext) {
        if (interceptionContext.Result.DataSpace != DataSpace.CSpace)
            return;

        var query = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
        if (query != null) {
            var modified = query.Query.Accept(new CustomInVisitor(_clientIds));
            interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(query.MetadataWorkspace, query.DataSpace, modified);
        }
    }

    private class CustomInVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor {
        private readonly int[] _clientIds;

        public CustomInVisitor(int[] clientIds) {
            _clientIds = clientIds;
        }

        public override DbExpression Visit(DbScanExpression expression) {
            var table = (EntityType) expression.Target.ElementType;
            // obviously use another way to filter
            // here I just check if there is Clients navigation property
            var prop = table.NavigationProperties.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Clients");
            if (prop == null)
                return expression;
            var binding = expression.Bind();
            // building x => x.Clients
            var propFilter = binding.VariableType
                .Variable(binding.VariableName)
                .Property(prop);
            // building list of DbConstantExpressions for In clause
            var list = _clientIds.Select(item => DbExpressionBuilder.Constant(item)).ToList();
            // building x => x.Clients.Any(client => clientIds.Contains(client.Id))
            var any = propFilter.Any(exp => exp.Property("Id").In(list));
            return binding.Filter(any);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that `table.NavigationProperties` collection is always empty in my case even if `Include` is presented in the intercepted query

Comment: @RomanKoliada ensure that you have `interceptionContext.Result.DataSpace != DataSpace.CSpace` condition and not just copied only visitor to your already existing interceptor (because in examples over internet they usually filter by CSSpace). And by the way `Include` is not needed in such query, you can remove it since it has no effect.

Comment: @RomanKoliada I've tested this today on EF database-first model I had and it worked (results in `where exists (select 1 from ... where Id IN (...))`) query.

Comment: Thanks, it's working for me too. You are right - I just copied visitor's code in my first try.